# When to use constructor and destructor, especially in containers and across threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, constructor, destructor

I have a multi-threaded program (a client-server one, but not necessarily relevant in this question) where multiple threads access global queues. There are two queues: `msgs_inc` and `clients_msg` which is of type `queue<msgInfo>`, where `msgInfo` is my class.

The first thread, receives a message from a client, does the following (relevant snippet):

```
msgInfo message_processed(message_fr_client); //line 1: takes in string 
msgs_inc.push(message_processed); //line 2
```

The second thread is supposed to retrieve from `msgs_inc`, process them, then push into `clients_msg`.

```
msgInfo msg_from_queue(msgs_inc); //line 3: retrieve from front of queue
msgs_inc.pop(); //line 4
clients_msg.push(msg_from_queue); //line 5
```

The third thread retrieves from `clients_msg`, after which it is no longer required.

```
msgInfo msg_from_queue(clients_msg); //line 6: retrieve from front of queue
clients_msg.pop(); //line 7
```

My question is:

1. In line 3, is this constructor -detailed below- known as a copy constructor vs. a standard constructor?
2. Am I wrong in 'instantiating' `msgInfo` twice i.e. once before pushing it in, and then again before retrieving it? Am I supposed to use a pointer or something else instead? It *feels* like it might inefficient, but I don't know another method.
3. When I do apply a destructor? Do I only apply it after line 7, when I no longer require it, or do I need to apply a destructor again at line 4 since I've already created another instance of `msgInfo` with the information?

My apologies for this tediousness - I can't find information about this and can't piece a concrete conclusion together.

---

This is my class:

```
class msgInfo
{
public:
    msgInfo();
    msgInfo(std::string); //creating instance fr string rxed fr client
    msgInfo(std::map<int, std::map<int, std::queue<msgInfo>>>, int, int); //creating instance for string to be sent to client

    ~msgInfo();

private:
    int source_id;
    int dest_id;
    int priority;
    std::string payload;
    std::list<int> nodePath;
};
```

The constructor used in line 3 and line 6:

```
msgInfo::msgInfo(std::queue<msgInfo> outgoing_msg)
{
    source_id = outgoing_msg.front().source_id;
    dest_id = outgoing_msg.front().dest_id;
    priority = outgoing_msg.front().priority;
    payload = outgoing_msg.front().payload;
    nodePath = outgoing_msg.front().nodePath;
}
```

Comment: "I can't find information about this" -- Have you tried google? For instance, when I google "copy constructor" I have no trouble finding out what one is, and seeing that yours isn't. I also find out that one does not apply a destructor ... it gets applied when the object is destroyed.

Comment: @JimBalter I did google, and it usually says "A copy constructor is a special constructor for a class/struct that is
used to make a copy of an existing instance." My question is that since I already pushed in an instance into the queue, and I have to create another instance to push it out, it isn't clear to me that it isn't a copy constructor? It does show [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/y8hv0pDG/) that there are certain formats, but I wondered if it was semantics.

Comment: That's not *all* it says. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_constructor "A copy constructor has as its first parameter a (possibly const or volatile) reference to its own class type."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would *not* use the constructor from a queue.  This is
confusing.  It's far better (and clearer) to write:

```
msgInfo msg_from_queue( msgs_inc.front() );
```

This invokes the copy constructor (since it makes a copy); in
your case, the copy constructor provided by the compiler is
sufficient.

As for instantiating `msgInfo` twice, you're actually
instantiating it more than that, since it gets copied from your
original instance into the queue, then from the queue to the
second thread.  There's nothing wrong with this.  C++ is
designed to privilege the use of value semantics, and doing
otherwise requires special handling.  If it later turns out that
the copying is a performance bottleneck, you can fix it then.
(Probably by making copy less expensive, rather than by moving
to pointers.  Get rid of that `std::list`, for example.)

If you do use pointers, you have to consider issues of
ownership.  You cannot just pass the address of a local
variable.  And having two or more threads access the same data
is illegal if anyone is modifying the data.

As for your last question: *you* don't call (I presume that's
what you mean by "apply") the destructor (at least when using
value semantics).  The compiler calls it automatically for local
variables, and the underlying container of the queue calls it
when the object is removed from the queue.  For that matter, you
don't call the constructor either: when you define an object,
the compiler calls it for you, and when the object is copied
into the queue, the queue performs the copy.

Finally, you've not shown any of your synchronization logic.
I presume that this is simply because you're removed it to
simplify the demonstration, and that you do know that you need
to synchronize access as soon as there are multiple threads.

Comment: thank you for this, it was precisely what I was trying to ask!

Comment: The problem with containers, locking and copying is the cost of the copy, both in terms of the direct time spent performing the copy, and the extended lock span required, so increasing the chance of contention.  If the object to be signaled to the other thread is either very large, (eg. a data buffer from a network connection), or very complex to copy, (eg. an object that references other objects), pointers are sensibly unavoidable. Things only get worse for values when the objects need forwarding on to other threads after handling, eg. to a GUI or logger.

Comment: @MartinJames He's just starting; let's not look for problems before they occur:-).  (Although I'm very suspicious about an `std::list` in the queued object.  Or anywhere, for that matter.)  All of my queues have used pointers, but that's because the messages have always been polymorphic.  The interface to my queues has also always taken an `std::auto_ptr`, which ensures that the sender doesn't access the object once it has been posted to the queue.  But the implementation _is_ more than just an `std::queue` (which couldn't contain an `std::auto_ptr` anyway).

Comment: @JamesKanze OK, you have a point,(er). I don't bother with anything more complex than a pointer for inter-thread comms.  If I queue off a pointer, I allocate, (or depool), another *object in the very next line of code, so making the queued-off pointer inaccessible to the producer.